# Spacing issues with unicode-math in lualatex but not xelatex

Tags: luatex

I am getting a spacing issue on a document if I compile with lualatex but not with xelatex. If I input `$Y \bigr]$`, the top serif of Y collides with the bracket in lualatex. Xelatex is handling this fine. This is happening on the default LM font.

Is there a fix for this, or is this just one of those quirks with lualatex?

**Edit:**

MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{unicode-math}
\begin{document}
$\bigl[Y\bigr]$
\end{document}
```

Log file: https://pastebin.com/cSBtCFet

Comment: Hmmm, an MWE would help checking things... anyway, a `\bigr` should have a `\bigl` somewhere to match, or am I wrong?

Comment: @Rmano Not necessarily.

Comment: @campa egreg thanks

Comment: you should show a complete example and the log-file.

Comment: @campa did you use unicode-math?

Comment: No, but you didn't mention that. That's why we always ask for a MWE. Now I can confirm the issue.